# "FormatException was unhandled" Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript

I have an error in my website and trying to resolve: Error "format exception was unhandled"
such that it work for both date time as well as with string and integer.

Please see the details and code from this link http://tinyurl.com/ydg3u7s

Thanks

Comment: Is there a question here that I miss?

Comment: If you miss it, your not the only one, Fredrik. This thread leaves me also confused.

Comment: I was looking for the solution of the question that i posted on other site and i gave an explanation of the error on that site which is too long so i posted link over here.

Comment: what kind of confusion webleeuw. Give me a pleasure to overcome with your confusion.

Comment: Well, if you've a question, it might be handy to form the sentence as a question, as well as posting the code of the problem here instead of referring to another site. What left me confused was what exactly the question was :).

Comment: OK
SRY FOR INCONVENIENCE.
I WILL KEEP THIS IN MIND FOR FUTURE REFRENCE
THX ANYWAY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Convert.ChangeType(IsThisObjectANull, DataTypeCode);
```

The conversion is probably failing due to incompatible types . You might have to debug and check when this happens .

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some try/catch mechanism?